# How to add eclipse server to an existing EC2 instance

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I previously created one EC2 instance through Elastic beanstalk using eclipse.
I used to deploy the application through eclipse itself. Now somehow, the server got unconfigured. 
When i am trying to reconfigure the server, it is creating a new instance of the application which i don't want. 
Can someone help me in configuring the existing EC2 in the eclipse project?
I am trying to update the configuration, but it is not able to fetch the server details(It is not showing any server in the server dropdown). However, server explorer is showing all the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanstalk will change its ec2 instances as it see fit. Therefore, it's ok that your instance has disappeared. The eclipse plugin is known to be buggy, and is good mostly for initial setup and demo, and not for ongoing work.
I do recommend installing the [EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) and using the command line to deploy your code (`eb deploy`).

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html and deployed my changes using eb deploy. After deployment, i am getting 404 error. Same changes are working on localhost. There is no environment level change, just minor change like log statement change. Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: make sure the files are committed. `eb deploy` takes the files from the local git directory.

Comment: Yes, all the files were committed. There has to be something else. i will try to debug and post once i get the root cause.